# Number of items for type 1 of 31.70 and type 2 of 116.90 to get a total of 2375.60 dollars

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I purchased a number of items that cost 31.70 each and some other items that cost 116.90 each.
The total cost of my purchases was 2375.60. How many items of each type did I purchase?

I know you can find the answer via brute force... is there any other way of calculating this sort of example, not to sure on what sort of formula i should use

Comment: The answer is $13$ of $116.90$ and $27$ of $31.70$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you multiply everything by $10$, you get the linear diophantine equation:

$$317x + 1169y = 23756$$

This is guaranteed a solution set in the integers because $\mathrm {gcd}(317,1169) = 1$ and $1$ clearly divides the $RHS$.

The issue is that such large numbers make for tedious mathematics.

A step by step solution can be generated using [this website](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~snburris/htdocs/linear.html). You can pretty much follow these steps in your by-hand working.

The general solution is $x = -1401604 + 1169n, y = 380096-317n$.

From those you can deduce that the unique value of $n$ that gives jointly positive $x$ and $y$ is $1199$, and the required solution is $x=27, y= 13$.